# How to check which version of Java is installed before a user tries to run an application?

Tags: java

If a user double-clicks on an executable JAR file, is it possible to check what version of Java that he or she has installed, and then display an appropriate message in a window that says that he or she needs to have X version of Java to run the application?

I am creating an application that requires Java 7, and if a user does not have that version installed, I would like to display a message that says that he or she needs to download and install it.

Of course, the user can type `java -version`, but it would be nice to display the version in a window for those who don't know how to check what version is installed. Is it possible to do so?

Or should I run some type of script to check before launching the application?

Comment: [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) has such an option.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `System.getProperty("java.version")`

You'll need to do some parsing, but this should give you a jumping of point

Comment: And you'll have to be extra careful that the code that does the check is actually compiled with an ancient enough Java. Otherwise even the check cannot be executed because of incompatible class versions.

Comment: If the api goes back from say java 1.1 and he is developing on 1.7 isn't the api backwards compatible?

Comment: @mpi I'm not sure that makes sense. If I run a program compiled with java 6, java 7 will run it. It only matters in reverse and it's likely that the earlier version of java won't even in the code. We use this check to make sure out users are using java 6.12+ and less the 7

Comment: @MPi sorry, I think I answered my own stupid question :P the question is then if you care or not, but it is a valid point

Answer (score 2):

You can get the java version by using 
`System.getProperty("java.version")`

See the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)